# Clear the selection of one ListBox if we select in another ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a scenario where two lists are to be shown in one window, but user can select in any one of the list only and proceed.

Lets say listbox1 and listbox2 if user select an item in listbox1 and again select from listbox2 the selected item in listbox1 should be removed.

I have to achieve this only through xaml not from codebehind. so I tried below:

```
  <Grid.Resources>
            <Storyboard  x:Key="temp" >
                <Int32Animation Storyboard.TargetName="lstbox"   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ListBox.SelectedIndex)" 
                                     To="-1" Duration="0:0:.2" />
            </Storyboard>
            <Storyboard  x:Key="temp1" >
                <Int32Animation Storyboard.TargetName="listBox1"   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ListBox.SelectedIndex)" 
                                     To="-1" Duration="0:0:.2" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Grid.Resources>
```

As above created two storyboards to set selectedIndex to -1 and called that story board when selection changed event trigger as shown below:

```
 <ListBox Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Grid.Column="1">
            <ListBox.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ListBox.SelectionChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource temp}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ListBox.Triggers>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="BlanchedAlmond" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Coffie"></ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Tea"></ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Orange Juice"></ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Milk"></ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Iced Tea"></ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Content="Mango Shake"></ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
  <ListBox Name="lstbox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}"  Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="lstbox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ListBox.SelectionChanged">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource temp1}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ListBox.Triggers>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="BlanchedAlmond" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkViolet" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

Through code behind when I set SelectedIndex to -1 styles for selectedItem are clearing but through storyboard the styles are not clearing.

Please tell anyother way or guide me to make it work.

I have to achieve it only through xaml.

Thanks,

Nagasree.

Comment: This should be handled in a view model and certainly not in the markup...

Comment: our project dynamically set the viewmodel. So I can't decide while implementing

Comment: So you're not using MVVM then? Because then you would certainly implement this in the view model of the view with the ListBox elements. Why do you still want to implement this kind of logic in XAML?

Comment: I have achieved it using attached behaviour and I don't know why negative for this question.Anyway thanks all for your inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample, if you change your storyboards like so, it will work:

```
        <Storyboard x:Key="temp">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                Storyboard.TargetName="lstbox"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="SelectedItem">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                        KeyTime="0:0:0"
                        Value="null" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>

        <Storyboard x:Key="temp1">
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                Storyboard.TargetName="listBox1"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="SelectedItem">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                        KeyTime="0:0:0"
                        Value="null" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames.KeyFrames>
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
```

However, like commenters mentioned. If you are using MVVM and databinding to SelectedItem, etc., this may not work.

If your boss will let you use a Behavior, you can do something like this:

```
<ListBox
    Name="ListBox1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyData1}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyData1, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:ListBoxSingleSelectionBehavior TargetListBox="{Binding ElementName=ListBox2}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="BlanchedAlmond" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
<ListBox
    Name="ListBox2"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyData2}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMyData2, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="BlanchedAlmond" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkViolet" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

And here is the behavior:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors;

namespace SO
{
    public class ListBoxSingleSelectionBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
    {
        private bool isSelectionChanging;

        public ListBoxSingleSelectionBehavior()
        {
        }

        #region TargetListBox (DependencyProperty)
        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the TargetListBox property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetListBoxProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "TargetListBox",
                typeof(ListBox),
                typeof(ListBoxSingleSelectionBehavior),
                new PropertyMetadata(null, OnTargetListBoxChanged));

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the target ListBox to monitor.
        /// </summary>
        public ListBox TargetListBox
        {
            get => (ListBox)GetValue(TargetListBoxProperty);
            set => SetValue(TargetListBoxProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnTargetListBoxChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var behavior = (ListBoxSingleSelectionBehavior) d;

            var oldTargetListBox = (ListBox) e.OldValue;
            var newTargetListBox = (ListBox) e.NewValue;

            behavior.OnTargetListBoxChanged(oldTargetListBox, newTargetListBox);
        }

        private void OnTargetListBoxChanged(ListBox oldTargetListBox, ListBox newTargetListBox)
        {
            if (oldTargetListBox != null)
            {
                oldTargetListBox.SelectionChanged -= OnTargetSelectionChanged;
            }

            if (newTargetListBox != null)
            {
                newTargetListBox.SelectionChanged += OnTargetSelectionChanged;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += OnSourceSelectionChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();

            if (AssociatedObject != null)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= OnSourceSelectionChanged;
            }
        }

        private void OnSourceSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isSelectionChanging) return;

            isSelectionChanging = true;

            if (TargetListBox != null)
            {
                TargetListBox.SelectedItem = null;
            }

            isSelectionChanging = false;
        }

        private void OnTargetSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isSelectionChanging) return;

            isSelectionChanging = true;

            if (AssociatedObject != null)
            {
                AssociatedObject.SelectedItem = null;
            }

            isSelectionChanging = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Keithernet.So we can't store the value if we use storyboard

Comment: Correct. In this case, your boss is asking for something impossible. You could write an attached behavior that would handle this. It would appear that it is being done in XAML, but it is still executing code in the behavior.

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of using a Behavior.

Comment: Thanks Keithernet I can use behaviours.